# Get the relative extrema from 1D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm writing code that includes the algorithm to find local maximum/minimum values in array. But I failed to find the proper function.

At first, I used `argrelextrema` in `scipy.signal`.

```
b = [6, 1, 3, 5, 5, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8, 7, 7, 13, 10]

scipy.signal.argrelextrema(np.array(b), np.greater)
scipy.signal.argrelextrema(np.array(b), np.greater_equal)
scipy.signal.argrelextrema(np.array(b), np.greater_equal, order=2)
```

The result is

```
(array([ 9, 20], dtype=int64),)
(array([ 0,  3,  4,  7,  9, 14, 15, 20], dtype=int64),)
(array([ 0,  3,  4,  9, 14, 15, 20], dtype=int64),)
```

First one didn't catch the `b[3]`(or `b[4]`). So I modified it to second one, using `np.greater_equal`. However, in this case, the first value `b[0]` is also treated as local maximum, and the value 2 in `b[7]` is included. By using third one, I could throw away `b[7]`. But `order=2` still also has problem when data is like `[1, 3, 1, 4, 1]` (it can't catch 3)

My expected result is

```
[3(or 4), 9, 14(or 15), 20]
```

I want to catch only one among `b[3], b[4]` (same value). I want some problems of `argrelextrema` I mentioned above to be solved. The code below succeeded.

```
scipy.signal.find_peaks(b)
```

the result is `[3, 9, 14, 20]`.

The code I'm writing is treating the pair of local maximum, and local minimum. So I want to find the local minimum in the same way. Is there any function like `scipy.signal.find_peaks` to find local minimum?

Answer (score 3):

You could simply apply `find_peaks` to the negative version of your array:

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

min_idx = find_peaks([-x for x in b])
```

Even more convenient when using numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
b = np.array(b)
min_idx = find_peaks(-b)
```

Comment: Oh... what a beautiful solution! Thanks